# Error when running Duplicity on AWS Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, duplicity

I have installed Duplicity on some AWS EC2 instances using the folowing command

```
yum -y install duplicity rsync gpg python python-devel python-pip --    enablerepo=epel
```

This was based on an approach described here

https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/backups/duplicity-amazon-s3/

However, whenever I try to run a duplictiy command, I get the following command

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 42, in <module> from duplicity import log ImportError: No module named duplicity
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
yum -y install duplicity rsync gpg python python-devel python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
pip install duplicity
```

If have an error like Unable to get SCM version: No module named setuptools_scm do this:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
pip install -U pip setuptools_scm
yum install librsync-devel
pip install duplicity
```

Answer (score -1):

check that your default PYTHONPATH is set up properly. there are very good howto's out there, so i am not duplicating them. simply search the net.

if not you can add the location where duplicity modules ended up manually via PYTHONPATH env var.

..ede/duply.net

PS: in my first answer i posted a link, but some clever editor deleted that "because the link may change in the future".